# Adding data labels to line graph in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, label

I have a hard time managing to add data labels to a matplotlib figure I'm creating. On bar graph I have no issue.
For easier troubleshooting, I simplified it as much as possible but still with the same issue.

I've looked relentlessly but couldn't find the answer...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = [10,11,12]
temp = [10,14,12]

temp_labels = plt.plot(dates,temp)

for x in temp_labels:
        label = temp[x]

        plt.annotate(label,
                     (x,temp[x]),
                     textcoords = "offset points"),
                     xytext = (0,10),
                     ha = "center")

plt.show()
```

I'm having an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "rain_notif.py", line 16, in <module>
       label = temp[x]
TypeError: list indices must be intergers or slices, not Line2D
```

Here is what I have and I just want to value label on top of each point.
[Figure without label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz7t4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `temp_labels` is a list of lines, so `x` is a line object, which cannot be used to index a list, as indicated by the error. Start from here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = [10,11,12]
temp = [10,14,12]

plt.plot(dates,temp)

for x, y in zip(dates, temp):
    label = y
    plt.annotate(label, (x, y),
                 xycoords="data",
                 textcoords="offset points",
                 xytext=(0, 10), ha="center")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that quick answer! I was wondering about the string thing, could have found that but the zip I wasn't near that solution.